# How to display the correct choice in red color in exam class?

Tags: environments, document-classes, exam

```
 \documentclass{exam}
   \printanswers
    \begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question Sample Question 1
    \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \choice Option3
    \correctchoice Option4
    \end{choices}
    \question Sample Question 2
    \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \correctchoice Option3
    \choice Option4
    \end{choices}
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

With the `\printanswers`command, correct choice gets bold. Instead of making it bold, is it possible to display the correct choice in red color font? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class provides the macro `\CorrectChoiceEmphasis` for that (section 5.7 of the manual). The default definition is

```
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\bfseries}
```

so you can write

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\color{red}\bfseries}
```

for boldface, red text (or remove `\bfseries` if you only want the text in red).

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\color{red}\bfseries}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Sample Question 1
\begin{choices}
\choice Option1
\choice Option2
\choice Option3
\correctchoice Option4
\end{choices}

\question Sample Question 2
\begin{choices}
\choice Option1
\choice Option2
    \correctchoice Option3
\choice Option4
\end{choices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer...!!!